# Linq to entities (not to objects). How to write this SQL query?

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities, group-by

How would you write this in Linq To Entities?

```
SELECT DATEPART(weekday, MessageBundles.Date) AS WeekDay, count(*) AS Count FROM MessageBundles GROUP BY DATEPART(weekday, MessageBundles.Date)
```

I tried something like this:

```
for (int day = 1; day <= 7; day = day + 1)
  pairs.Add("[" + day + ", " + db.Messages.Count(m => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", m.Date) == day) + "]");
```

But it throws an exception saying "it can not be translated into a store expression" (that is: SqlFunctions is not supported)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of provider SQL CE, which doesnt support translating SqlFunctions.DatePart(...).

But when deploying (provider SqlClient) worked fine.

Too sad that in localhost I wont be able to play with that.